# Combining resources in Python with Flask

Tags: python, flask

I' trying to combine two independent Flask apps like the example below:

```
from geventwebsocket import WebSocketServer, Resource
```

...

```
server = WebSocketServer(('', 8080), Resource({
        '/': frontend,
        '/one': flask_app_one,
        '/two': flask_app_two})) 

server.serve_forever()
```

Inside each Flask app I declare the full path, isn't that suppose to be relative path, inside flask_app_one:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/one/ping')
def ping():
    return 'hello\n'
```

Why I should specify in     @app.route('/one/ping') instead of just @app.route('/ping') since all traffic to /one will be forwarded to the corresponding app?

Let me know if you need any additional info I kept my example clean
Thank you

Comment: Presumably because Flask doesn't know about geventwebsocket being used and it's therefore behaving as a normal webserver (which expects the path including the `/one`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have managed to do it with the so called Application Dispatching and the resources found in this page:

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/appdispatch/#app-dispatch

Thanks